# Transitioning xAxis and data at the same time - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a sort of timeline chart using D3.js. I've got most of the control logic worked out but my data points aren't behaving as expected as I move between pages. The timeline shows a 3 hour window of a data collection lasting one week. The user can click arrows at the left and right to move forwards and backwards in three hour blocks.

As a result of fetching the next three hours worth of data on each click, I expected the exit() function to contain all of the previous data points, because they should all be leaving the screen, but this doesn't seem to happen. Instead it removes 5 of the 10 points on the first page. I could get the behaviour I want by not using exit() and manually forcing the removal of all the points but I'd rather understand why it's not working with exit().

To complicate matters, as data exits and enters the chart it is transitioned in from right to left. At the same time I transition the domain bounds of the xAxis to give the appearance of the user moving forward in time. I'm starting to suspect that its this transition that is causing the exit() function to get confused as to what should and shouldn't be on the chart.

I've included a section of my code that deals with the removal of elements exiting the chart. Let me know if any other code snippets are needed.

```
elements = svg.selectAll('.news').data(data.items);

// Remove
                var exitingLabels = elements.exit(),
                    updatingLabels = elements,
                    creatingLabels = elements.enter();

                console.log(exitingLabels.selectAll('rect'));
                console.log(updatingLabels.selectAll('rect'));
                console.log(creatingLabels);

                exitingLabels.selectAll('circle')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .ease('sin-in-out')
                    .attr('cx', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').clone().subtract(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format('x')) + 29;});

                exitingLabels.selectAll('line')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .ease('sin-in-out')
                    .attr('x1', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').clone().subtract(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format('x')) + 29;})
                    .attr('x2', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').clone().subtract(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format('x')) + 29;});

                exitingLabels.selectAll('rect')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .ease('sin-in-out')
                    .attr('x', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').clone().subtract(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format('x'));});

                exitingLabels.selectAll(function() { return this.getElementsByTagName('foreignObject'); })
                    .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .ease('sin-in-out')
                    .attr('x', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').clone().subtract(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format('x'));});

                exitingLabels.transition()
                    .delay(1600)
                    .each('end', function(a){console.log(a);})
                    .remove();
```

data.items is the result of an async call to fetch new data, this code is within the callback of that function.

Comment: You need to specify a key function to `.data()`, otherwise it will match by index, e.g. `.data(data.items, function(d) { return d; })` to match by the data.

Comment: Perfect that was the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a key function to `.data()`, otherwise it will match by index. E.g. `.data(data.items, function(d) { return d; })` to match by the actual data.